# Android Gstreamer rtmp Support

Tags: android, gstreamer

I am developing a Video player Application using Gstreamer which can play RTMP streaming links.Is there any way to play RTMP links using Gstramer. RTMP plugin is not supported in latest Gstreamer SDK.
Thanks

Comment: What is the version of Gstreamer SDK?

Comment: i have gstreamer-0.10 sdk

Comment: Hello gstreamer-0.10 is out of date. You should use 1.0 version. http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/android/1.4.5/. It has rtmp plugin

Comment: Thank you but it has a linking issue with android NDK.